# An alternative saying for "it may be cheaper to build a new house than to renovate an old one"?

Tags: idioms

I'm looking to communicate the idea that performing a task would be less costly (more than just financially; technically, or when risk is considered) if you start from scratch or anew, instead of attempting to alter or change some existing object or entity.

The closest phrase I can think of that satisfies this is "it may be cheaper to build a new house than to renovate an old one". What other sayings exist?

Comment: Like his contractor friend told my dad after he bought an old farmhouse:  "Insure it, then burn it down."

Comment: Just ask, “What about the existing solution is worth holding on to?”

Comment: [The Money Pit (1986)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091541/)

Comment: "[It is] cheaper to replace [it] than repair [it]."

Answer (score 1):

There is a phrase in the novel *Brave New World*:

**Ending is better than mending** ([WikiQuote](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Brave_New_World#Chapter_3))

The phrase is a slogan taught subliminally (via a process dubbed "hypnopædia"):

> A government slogan encouraging people to throw away old possessions and buy new ones, thus theoretically keeping the global economy strong.

So to use it literally would be to miss the point of the satiric context, but it would suffice for your needs.